# current_user considered nil after login raises NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-state

After login I receive an Action Controller Exception:

*NoMethodError in StaticPages#home* 
*undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass*

What is considered nil is `current_user` at line 12 of the following `_comment.html.erb` partial:

```
<li id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
    <%= link_to gravatar_for(comment.user, size: 30), comment.user %>
    <span class="comment-content"><%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>&nbsp;<%= comment.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
        <% if current_user?(comment.user) %>
            <%= link_to "delete", comment, method: :delete, remote: true %>
        <% end %>
    </span>
    <% if logged_in? && (current_user == comment.user || current_user = comment.micropost.user) %>
        <div class="reply-section">
            <%= link_to gravatar_for(current_user, size: 20), current_user %>
            <%= form_for(current_user.replies.build) do |f| %>
                <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
                <div><%= f.hidden_field :comment_id, value: comment.id %></div>
                <div class="reply-box">
                    <%= f.text_area :content, rows: "1", class: "reply_area" %>
                </div>
                <%= f.submit "Reply", class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="replies-section">
        <% if comment.replies.any? %>
            <ol id="replies_comment-<%= comment.id %>">
                <% comment.replies.each do |reply| %>
                    <%= render reply %>
                <% end %>
            </ol>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</li>
```

The email of the exception is the email in the definition of `gravatar_for`. 
If I remove the 12th line, the raised exception is *undefined method 'replies' for nil:NilClass*, that is `current_user` in the following line. 
The above partial is inserted in the micropost partial as `<%= render comment %>`. I tried to add the code directly in the micropost partial but the exception is raised anyway.

The piece of code raising the exception belongs to the Reply feature: a user can post a micropost, a comment to a micropost, and a reply to a comment.

I do not understand why `current_user` is considered nil after login. 
`current_user` is defined in the session helper as follows:

```
def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
        user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
            log_in user
            @current_user = user
        end
    end
end
```

Two lines above the conditional, `if logged_in?` checks just that `current_user` be not nil, since method `logged_in?` is defined as `!current_user.nil?` Moreover, `current_user` is called plenty of times in the micropost partial, where the comment partial is inserted, but rails starts raising the exception at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your condition:

```
<% if logged_in? && (current_user == comment.user || current_user = comment.micropost.user) %>
```

You are assigning `current_user` instead of checking it which is causing the issue:

```
current_user = comment.micropost.user
```

There should be `==` instead of `=` and the `comment.micropost.user` is nil which is assigned to `current_user` and it is throwing you exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here:

```
<% if logged_in? && (current_user == comment.user || current_user = comment.micropost.user) %>
```

You are assigning `comment.micropost.user` to `current_user` instead of comparing its value.

So, when reaching that point you get an error because `current_user` value is set with whatever value you had in `comment.micropost.user` and, since it is not a valid `id` you get `nil` from `current_user`.

To solve the issue Just change `=` to `==`:

```
<% if logged_in? && (current_user == comment.user || current_user == comment.micropost.user) %>
```